# Making a canvas ball move smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I wrote a multiplayer pong game, but because of a ~60ms lag my bouncing ball is not moving smoothly. [The game itself is available here](https://scyk.pl/games), but since it works only on chrome, and the site itself is written in my native language (also you obviously need two browsers in order for it to work), here is jsfiddle of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/yc6Lb/75/

As you can see in the fiddle, `dx` and `dy` are defined and the refreshes per second is defined as `speed`. I need those three variables to remain constant (I know that they are causing the ball to not move smoothly).

Now the question: Are there any tricks to not touch those variables, but make the ball look like it moves smoothly? I was thinking about rendering the new position of the ball + rendering previous position of the ball with 50% opacity, but I have yet to test it. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to touch the `dx`, `dy`, and `speed`? More frequent updates make for smoother animations.

Comment: @JasonP: First of all, in my original app, `dx, dy` are as small as possible (values 1 and 2). So there's that. `Speed` cannot be changed because of the lag that is between client and server (about 50ms), and I cannot do anything about that either. So I need some kind of a trick here.

Comment: What if you were to let the game animate on it's own on the client, and only make changes when necessary to sync with the server? Also, you can make the step smaller than one.

Comment: @JasonP: That's something that I would not want to change. But I will try with changing dx and dy to `0.5 and 1` and see what happens.

Comment: @JasonP has your solution.  Pong logic would allow you to let each user do 1 course correction that must be transmitted across the network.  After that, the ball's path across the pong field can be automatically calculated and animated entirely on both clients' computers.  No more network traffic is required until the other player does their course correction.

Comment: I've modified your code below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, as @Jason said, that you could have the step as precise as you want in the animation (using animationFrame for instance), and handle separately the issue of getting the remote information.
However, for a quick fix you could use that trick i sometimes use : have a trail/shadow effect by clearing the context2d with lowered opacity.
So the clear function becomes :

```
function clear() {
  cxt.globalAlpha=0.3;
  cxt.fillStyle='#FFFFFF';
  cxt.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  cxt.globalAlpha=1;
}
```

then you must not clear in the draw() function, and call to clear() in the draw loop.

i updated your fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/yc6Lb/86/

play with the alpha to get the effect you want.

Rq : you might want to clear with full opacity some parts of the screen ( like the score ), and use lower opacity only in the animated part of the canvas.

Comment: +1 Nice motion effect!  I'm unclear about the OP's question...are they asking how to deal with a sluggish animation or instead are they asking how to deal with the network latency between client and server? I worry they are having the server transmit each ball position instead of having that calculation/animation done on the client-side.

Comment: Thx, i love it too ! a low-cost stencil buffer ! The question seems to be about hiding a bad animation, but in fact, yes, having a fixed time frame won't spare the efforts to handle both player's clock and try to guess the other one's actual position. So @ojek should go for animation frame, and start coding the tricky lag computations :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is ugly, but here's a FPS reference for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/yc6Lb/84/

Specifically using `requestAnimationFrame()` and having a FPS counter. Note the performance difference :)

Here's a **BEAUTIFUL CODE** version: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/Ey9uz/1/
You're most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can gain a little bit of performance from not doing your 2*pi calc in every loop. Round it to a static value of 6.28.

You may also want to look at [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), which may speed things up.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with your math.
You should be using requestAnimationFrame.
Change your init function so that it looks like this:

```
function init() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(init, cxt)
  draw();  
}
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d131/936Mm/)

You'll probably also need a [polyfill for requestAnimationFrame](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) to get it working on all browsers.